# C++ Huffman coder and decoder

Tags: c++, compression

I've implemented a [Huffman encoder and decoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).

The code is a bit long, I'm worrying if it is easy to grasp it. Also it is my first time using `std::shared_ptr<>`, so I'm worrying if I used them in a most effective way.

Any comments are welcome.

**Huffman.cpp:**

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <queue>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct HuffmanTreeNode
{
    unsigned int weight;
    char c;

    std::shared_ptr<HuffmanTreeNode> left = nullptr, right = nullptr;

    friend bool operator<(const HuffmanTreeNode& t1, const HuffmanTreeNode& t2)
    {
        return t1.weight > t2.weight; // to have a min-heap priority queue
    }
};

void get_codes_from_tree(const HuffmanTreeNode& tree, std::map<char, std::string>& codes, std::string current_code="")
{
    if(!tree.left && !tree.right) // leave
        codes[tree.c] = current_code;
    else
    {
        if(tree.left)
            get_codes_from_tree(*tree.left, codes, current_code + "0");
        if(tree.right)
            get_codes_from_tree(*tree.right, codes, current_code + "1");
    }
}

HuffmanTreeNode get_tree_from_codes(std::vector<std::string> codes)
{
    HuffmanTreeNode root;

    std::vector<std::string> left_codes, right_codes;
    for(std::string code: codes)
    {
        if(!code.empty())
        {
            if(code[0] == '0')
                left_codes.push_back(code.substr(1));
            else
                right_codes.push_back(code.substr(1));
        }
    }

    if(!left_codes.empty())
    {
        HuffmanTreeNode l = get_tree_from_codes(left_codes);
        root.left = std::shared_ptr<HuffmanTreeNode>(new HuffmanTreeNode(l));
    }
    if(!right_codes.empty())
    {
        HuffmanTreeNode r = get_tree_from_codes(right_codes);
        root.right = std::shared_ptr<HuffmanTreeNode>(new HuffmanTreeNode(r));
    }

    return root;
}

std::string next_bin(std::string bin)
{
    int k = bin.size() - 1;
    while(bin[k] == '1')
    {
        bin[k] = '0';
        k--;
    }
    if(k == -1)
        bin = "1" + bin;
    else
        bin[k] = '1';
    return bin;
}

// get canonical huffman codes from the sizes of the original huffman codes
std::map<char, std::string> get_canonical_codes(std::vector<int> code_sizes)
{
    int min_size = 0, max_size = 0;
    for(int n: code_sizes)
    {
        if(n > 0 && (min_size == 0 || n < min_size))
            min_size = n;
        if(n > max_size)
            max_size = n;
    }

    std::string bin(min_size, '0');
    std::map<char, std::string> canonical_codes;

    for(int i = min_size; i <= max_size; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < code_sizes.size(); j++)
        {
            if(code_sizes[j] == i)
            {
                canonical_codes[j] = bin;
                bin = next_bin(bin);
            }
        }
        bin += "0";
    }

    return canonical_codes;
}

int bin_to_dec(std::string bin)
{
    int dec = 0;
    int n = bin.size();
    int k = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(bin[n-1-i] == '1')
            dec += k;
        k *= 2;
    }
    return dec;
}

// if nb_bits > 1, add 0s at the beginning of the output strings so that its size is nb_bits
std::string dec_to_bin(int dec, int nb_bits=-1)
{
    std::string bin;
    while(dec != 0)
    {
        if(dec % 2 == 0)
        {
            bin = "0" + bin;
            dec /= 2;
        }
        else
        {
            bin = "1" + bin;
            dec = (dec - 1) / 2;
        }
    }

    if(nb_bits > 0 && bin.size() < nb_bits)
    {
        std::string fill(nb_bits - bin.size(), '0');
        return fill + bin;
    }
    return bin;
}

/**
-3 bits: number of bits (between 0 and 7 which represents numbers from 1 to 8) used to represent the size of each code
-256 bits: for each char, 0 if the char has no code and 1 if the char's code size will be sent
-encoded message
-between 0 and 7 blank 1s to fill the last byte
*/
std::string huffman(const std::string& input)
{
    if(input.empty())
        return "";

    // get counts for each char
    std::map<char, unsigned int> weights;
    for(char c: input)
        weights[c] += 1;

    // build priority queue with leaves
    std::priority_queue<HuffmanTreeNode> nodes;
    for(auto kv: weights)
    {
        HuffmanTreeNode node;
        node.c = kv.first;
        node.weight = kv.second;
        nodes.push(node);
    }

    // construct Huffman tree
    while(nodes.size() > 1)
    {
        HuffmanTreeNode node1 = nodes.top();
        nodes.pop();
        HuffmanTreeNode node2 = nodes.top();
        nodes.pop();

        HuffmanTreeNode node_fusion;
        node_fusion.weight = node1.weight + node2.weight;
        node_fusion.left = std::shared_ptr<HuffmanTreeNode>(new HuffmanTreeNode(node1));
        node_fusion.right = std::shared_ptr<HuffmanTreeNode>(new HuffmanTreeNode(node2));

        nodes.push(node_fusion);
    }
    HuffmanTreeNode huffman_tree = nodes.top();

    // get codes from Huffman tree recursively
    std::map<char, std::string> codes;
    get_codes_from_tree(huffman_tree, codes);

    // get canonical Huffman codes
    std::vector<int> code_sizes;
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        code_sizes.push_back(codes[(char)i].size());
    codes = get_canonical_codes(code_sizes);

    // no code of length < 8 can contain only ones
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        if(code_sizes[i] > 0 && code_sizes[i] < 8 && codes[(char)i] == std::string(codes[(char)i].size(), '1'))
        {
            codes[(char)i] += "0";
            code_sizes[i]++;
        }
    }

    // add header to output
    std::string bin_output;

    int nb_codes = codes.size();
    int longest_code_size = *std::max_element(code_sizes.begin(), code_sizes.end()); // between 1 and 256
    int nb_max_bits_for_code_size = ceil(log2(longest_code_size)); // between 1 and 8, number of bits to represent each code size

    bin_output += dec_to_bin(nb_max_bits_for_code_size - 1, 3);
        // add which code sizes will be sent
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        if(code_sizes[i] == 0)
            bin_output += "0";
        else
            bin_output += "1";
    }
        // add code sizes
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        if(code_sizes[i] > 0)
            bin_output += dec_to_bin(code_sizes[i] - 1, nb_max_bits_for_code_size);

    }

    // add encoded string to output
    std::string output;
    for(char c: input)
    {
        bin_output += codes[c];
        while(bin_output.size() >= 8)
        {
            output += bin_to_dec(bin_output.substr(0, 8));
            bin_output.erase(0, 8);
        }
    }

    // add blank ones to fill the last byte
    if(!bin_output.empty())
        bin_output += std::string(8 - bin_output.size(), '1');
    output += bin_to_dec(bin_output.substr(0, 8));

    return output;
}


/**
-3 bits: number of bits (between 0 and 7 which represents numbers from 1 to 8) used to represent the size of each code
-256 bits: for each char, 0 if the char has no code and 1 if the char's code size will be sent
-encoded message
-between 0 and 7 blank 1s to fill the last byte
*/
std::string ihuffman(const std::string& input)
{
    std::string bin_input;
    int input_i = 0;
    int n = input.size();

    // header max size: 3+256+256*8 = 2307 bits < 289 bytes
    // get enough data to extract header
    while(input_i < std::min(n, 289))
    {
        bin_input += dec_to_bin((int)(unsigned char)input[input_i], 8);
        input_i++;
    }

    // extract header
    int nb_bits_for_code_size = bin_to_dec(bin_input.substr(0, 3)) + 1; // shift back from 0-7 to 1-8
    bin_input.erase(0, 3);

        // get which codes are sent
    std::map<char, int> code_sizes;
    std::vector<int> sent_code_sizes_indexs;
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        if(bin_input[i] == '1')
            sent_code_sizes_indexs.push_back(i);
    }
    bin_input.erase(0, 256);

        // get the sent codes sizes
    int bin_input_i = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < sent_code_sizes_indexs.size(); i++)
    {
        std::string bin_code_size = bin_input.substr(bin_input_i, nb_bits_for_code_size);
        code_sizes[(char)sent_code_sizes_indexs[i]] = bin_to_dec(bin_code_size) + 1;
        bin_input_i += nb_bits_for_code_size;
    }
    bin_input.erase(0, sent_code_sizes_indexs.size() * nb_bits_for_code_size);

    // get canonical huffman codes
    std::vector<int> code_sizes_vect;
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        code_sizes_vect.push_back(code_sizes[(char)i]);
    std::map<char, std::string> codes = get_canonical_codes(code_sizes_vect);

    // build associated huffman tree (without the chars at the leaves)
    std::vector<std::string> code_strings;
    for(auto code: codes)
        code_strings.push_back(code.second);

    std::shared_ptr<HuffmanTreeNode> root(new HuffmanTreeNode(get_tree_from_codes(code_strings)));

    // process the output
    std::string output;

    std::map<std::string, char> decodes;
    for(auto kv: codes)
        decodes[kv.second] = kv.first;

    std::string current_code;
    std::shared_ptr<HuffmanTreeNode> current_node = root;

    while(input_i < n || !bin_input.empty())
    {
        if(input_i < n)
        {
            bin_input += dec_to_bin((int)(unsigned char)input[input_i], 8);
            input_i++;
        }

        while(!bin_input.empty())
        {
            current_code += bin_input[0];
            if(bin_input[0] == '0')
                current_node = current_node->left;
            else
                current_node = current_node->right;
            bin_input.erase(0, 1);

            if(!current_node) // blanc '1' bits at the end
                return output;
            if(!current_node->left && !current_node->right) // leave
            {
                output += decodes[current_code];
                current_code = "";
                current_node = root;
            }
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Huffman.cpp"

int main()
{
    std::cout << ihuffman(huffman("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."));
}
```

Comment: Why _"syntax review2_? Doesn't your compiler already do this?

Comment: You might want to change the text portion of your question: Is it commented enough that someone can extend or maintain the program? Am I using shared pointers properly?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I've removed off topic part and I hope I improved wording. It should be fine now.

Answer (score 7):

Your public interface can be as simple as

```
std::string huffman(const std::string& input);
std::string ihuffman(const std::string& input);
```

On that matter, the rest of the functions and even the struct are probably better off as local to the translation unit (i.e. wrapped in an anonymous namespace):

```
namespace {
    // Code here
}

std::string huffman(const std::string& input) { ... }
std::string ihuffman(const std::string& input) { ... }
```

---

Also, you are not using a header file. In `main.cpp`, you wrote:

> ```
> #include "Huffman.cpp"
> ```

This is bad. You almost never want to directly include a source file, only header files. Instead, write a *Huffman.h* file:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

std::string huffman(const std::string& input);
std::string ihuffman(const std::string& input);
```

Also, note that you usually want to use namespaces:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

namespace huffman {
    std::string huffman(const std::string& input);
    std::string ihuffman(const std::string& input);
}
```

At this point, you might realize that `huffman::huffman(myString)` looks kind of ridiculous. Indeed, using the namespace brings out that you could name these functions better as `encode` and `decode`:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

namespace huffman {
    std::string encode(const std::string& input);
    std::string decode(const std::string& input);
}
```

After these changes, your source file is changed to be:

```
#include "Huffman.h" // it is best to put the associated header as the first include
// other includes...

// other code...

std::string huffman::encode(const std::string& input) { ... }
std::string huffman::decode(const std::string& input) { ... }
```

---

> ```
> struct HuffmanTreeNode
> {
>     unsigned int weight;
>     char c;
>
>     std::shared_ptr<HuffmanTreeNode> left = nullptr, right = nullptr;
>
>     friend bool operator<(const HuffmanTreeNode& t1, const HuffmanTreeNode& t2)
>     {
>         return t1.weight > t2.weight; // to have a min-heap priority queue
>     }
> };
> ```

First, you do not want to be using `std::shared_ptr` here. Simple tree-based data structures are better modeled with `std::unique_ptr`, as `unique_ptr` is much cheaper than `shared_ptr` (for one, there's no reference count, and it can also frequently be compiled down to the same code as raw `new`s and `delete`s). The only time you might want to use a `std::shared_ptr` for a tree is if you are allowing anyone to take a `HuffmanTreeNode` and keep it alive — in this case, the `shared_ptr` prevents the nodes from being deleted too early.

The `operator<` does not need to be a friend because `HuffmanTreeNode` is a `struct`. This also works:

```
struct HuffmanTreeNode
{
    unsigned int weight;
    char c;

    std::shared_ptr<HuffmanTreeNode> left = nullptr, right = nullptr;
};

bool operator<(const HuffmanTreeNode& t1, const HuffmanTreeNode& t2)
{
    return t1.weight > t2.weight; // to have a min-heap priority queue
}
```

`friend` makes it so a function (or a class) can access the private and protected members of a class. Since you declared it as a `struct`, everything is by default public, so friend is completely unneeded. Also note that a function declared as a `friend` inside a class is effectively declared in the enclosing namespace, so the two versions above are actually equivalent.

> ```
>     friend bool operator<(const HuffmanTreeNode& t1, const HuffmanTreeNode& t2)
>     {
>         return t1.weight > t2.weight; // to have a min-heap priority queue
>     }
> ```

This is not intuitive for an `operator<`; it appears to be making the comparison `>`. This would be better:

```
bool operator<(const HuffmanTreeNode& t1, const HuffmanTreeNode& t2)
{
    return t1.weight < t2.weight;
}
```

It might even be better to forgo the operator altogether, as with this operator, you might have `!(n1 < n2) && !(n2 < n1)`, but `n1 != n2` because the `char` is different. This breaks some expectations.

You were defining the `operator<` for use with a `std::priority_queue`, but you could just as well define a comparator struct.

---

> ```
> void get_codes_from_tree(const HuffmanTreeNode& tree, std::map<char, std::string>& codes, std::string current_code="")
> ```

A function with the name `get_foo` should return a value, but this function returns `void`.

Also, since the operation isn't cheap, and "get" tends to bring to mind a getter, I would instead use the word "compute" or something similar.

I would expect the signature to look more like:

```
std::map<char, std::string> compute_codes_from_tree(const HuffmanTreeNode& tree);
```

`current_code` is an implementation detail and does not need to be on the interface to this function.

Also, note that you take a `const HuffmanTreeNode&` as your first parameter. You are effectively defining a member function on `HuffmanTreeNode`. Why not put it there?

```
struct HuffmanTreeNode
{
    unsigned int weight;
    char c;

    std::shared_ptr<HuffmanTreeNode> left = nullptr, right = nullptr;

    std::map<char, std::string> compute_codes() const;
};
```

At this point, you might have to define a constructor for `HuffmanTreeNode`, in which case you might as well make it a full fledged `class`.

Also note that you have `HuffmanTreeNode`s which you are treating as entire trees. This tends to be harder to understand; I would instead recommend having a `HuffmanTree` class which internally has nodes as an implementation detail:

```
class HuffmanTree
{
    struct Node
    {
        unsigned int weight;
        char c;

        std::shared_ptr<HuffmanTreeNode> left = nullptr, right = nullptr;
    };

    Node root;
public:
    // constructor

    std::map<char, std::string> compute_codes() const;
};
```

This might be overkill if you only use the `HuffmanTree` inside the one source file *Huffman.cpp*, but you definitely want to do this if the class will be used externally to the source file as well.

---

> ```
> HuffmanTreeNode get_tree_from_codes(std::vector<std::string> codes)
> ```

You aren't actually consuming `codes`; that is, you don't take ownership of the vector (you wouldn't be making a copy anyway). This is a sign that it should be a `const&`. As a general rule of thumb, make function parameters `const&` unless you would be making a copy of them, then take them by value:

```
HuffmanTreeNode get_tree_from_codes(const std::vector<std::string>& codes)
```

Naturally, this could be a constructor of the `HuffmanTree` class instead, or possibly a static factory function.

---

> ```
> std::vector<std::string> left_codes, right_codes;
> ```

Try to avoid declaring two variables on the same line. Instead, make them separate declarations:

```
std::vector<std::string> left_codes;
std::vector<std::string> right_codes;
```

---

> ```
> for(std::string code: codes)
> {
>     if(!code.empty())
>     {
>         if(code[0] == '0')
>             left_codes.push_back(code.substr(1));
>         else
>             right_codes.push_back(code.substr(1));
>     }
> }
> ```

It tends to improve readability to put a space between `for`, `if`, etc and the opening `(` (like so: `for (`), although it is a matter of style.

> ```
> for(std::string code: codes)
> ```

This copies every string in `codes`, at the very least write `for (const std::string& code : codes)`.

Even better, use a standard algorithm. In general, whenever you write a `for` loop, especially a for each loop, look for a standard algorithm.

In this case, [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) comes to mind (this would make it so that you would take `codes` by value, as it modifies the range):

```
auto middle = std::partition(codes.begin(), codes.end(), [](const auto& code) {
    return code[0] == '0';
});
```

Then to create `left_codes` and `right_codes`:

```
std::vector<std::string> left_codes(codes.begin(), middle);
std::vector<std::string> right_codes(middle, codes.end());
```

Removing the first char could be done with `std::transform`.

---

> ```
> root.left = std::shared_ptr<HuffmanTreeNode>(new HuffmanTreeNode(l));
> ```

Use `std::make_shared`. Not only does it avoid potential problems with memory leaks, it also is more efficient because it can declare the reference count in the same block of memory as the allocated object:

```
 root.left = std::make_shared<HuffmanTreeNode>(l);
```

Also note that `l` is a bad name for a variable:

```
1l
```

Both `1` and `l` and `I` look similar in some fonts, and you can avoid it by using a more descriptive name such as `left`.

About the memory leak, IIRC, the following code could leak (before C++17):

```
f(std::shared_ptr<Type>{ new Type }, some_function());
```

Basically, the compiler is allowed to order the assembly such that the following happens (psuedocode):

```
auto* type = new Type
auto result = some_function()
auto ptr = std::shared_ptr<Type>{ type }
f(ptr, result)
```

If `some_function()` throws, then you leak memory.

---

> ```
> std::string huffman(const std::string& input)
> {
>    ...
> }
> ```

This function is really big. It's 97 lines long. Break it up into smaller functions. Notice how you have comments for several small sections of code? Those are ideal for turning into functions. Yes, you will have many functions, but the readability greatly improves.

However, many of your "functions" can be replaced with standard algorithms.